# Recibo un dato vacio desde php (enviado por fetch)

Tags: javascript, php, html5, mysqli, fetch

Estoy enviando un id por fetch a php para obtener el nombre de un proyecto. Ahora bien ejecuto un console_log para verificar que la consulta se haya efectuado correctamente pero solo aparece un espacio en blanco o vacío. Por favor ayuda no lo quiero enviar por GET (que si funciona) ya que me dijeron que es una mala práctica enviar ID por los Urls

Javascript, donde se captura el id al hacer clic y se envía el id por fetch

```
var enlaces=document.getElementsByClassName('enlace');
for(let el of enlaces){
    el.addEventListener('click', obtener_id_proyecto);
}
function obtener_id_proyecto(e){
 e.preventDefault();
console.log('presionaste en un proyecto');
var id_p=this.id;

//Enviando datos por Fetch
let datos=new FormData();
datos.append('id', id_p);


fetch('inc/funciones/funciones.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
    body: JSON.stringify(datos)
})
    .then(function(response) {
       if(response.ok) {
           return response.text();
       } else {
           throw "Error en la llamada Ajax";
       }
      })
    .then(function(datosRecididos){console.log(datosRecididos)});
}
```

PHP

```
   function obtenerNombreProyecto(){
  $id_proyecto=$_POST['id'];

include 'conexion.php';
try{
    

    $sql= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = {$id_proyecto}");
    return json_encode($sql);

} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error! : ". getMessage($e);
    return false;
}
```

}
Llamando la función Obtenernombreproyecto

```
<?php 
    $proyecto=obtenerNombreProyecto();


     if ($proyecto): ?>           

 
    <h1> Proyecto Actual:
        <?php foreach ($proyecto as $nombre): ?>
        <span><?php echo $nombre['nombre']; ?></span>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </h1>

    <form action="#" class="agregar-tarea">
        <div class="campo">
            <label for="tarea">Tarea:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Tarea" class="nombre-tarea"> 
        </div>
        <div class="campo enviar">
            <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $id_proyecto; ?>" value="id_proyecto">
            <input type="submit" class="boton nueva-tarea" value="Agregar">
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <?php 
        else:
            //Si no hay proyectos seleccionado
            echo "<p>Selecciona un Proyecto a la izquierda</p>";
        endif;

     ?>
```

Captura de la consola
https://prnt.sc/9Cr8fKRuqAX1

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No se ve cómo llamas a `obtenerNombreProyecto()` en tu código PHP. Las funciones no se llaman solas. Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta agregando esa parte del código.

Comment: Todo listo campeón, es decir ya coloque lo que faltaba. Gracias por la observación

Comment: Pero aún así, el resultado del query debería mostrarse en la consola, es para checar que trajo el nombre del proyecto correcto

Comment: Te dejé un mensaje en el chat para poder realizar pruebas online

Comment: Me parece que lo que tienes es un lío. ¿Por qué creas un `form` dentro del bloque `if ($proyecto): ?>`? Cuando trabajas entre cliente (Javascript) y servidor (PHP) por lo general el cliente recibe una respuesta casi siempre en formato JSON y consume esa respuesta. ¿Qué sentido tiene ahí el eventual `form` que estarías creando?

Comment: @A.Cedano el form es para las tareas del proyecto que estoy llamando que aún no he enviado. Según se llama un proyecto se le pueden asignar tareas

Answer (score 0):

Estas enviando y recibiendo bien el los datos ?

Comprueba esta salida en la `consola` del navegador debe ser un `Json valido`, puedes validar con esta [herramienta](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

```
var enlaces=document.getElementsByClassName('enlace');
for(let el of enlaces){
    el.addEventListener('click', obtener_id_proyecto);
}
function obtener_id_proyecto(e){
 e.preventDefault();
console.log('presionaste en un proyecto');
var id_p=this.id;

//Enviando datos por Fetch
let datos=new FormData();
datos.append('id', id_p);

//linea agregada 
console.log(JSON.stringify(datos))

fetch('inc/funciones/funciones.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
    body: JSON.stringify(datos)
})
.then(resp => resp.text())
.then(resp => {
  console.log(resp)
})
```

Ahora debes validar si estas recibiendo los datos correctamente en la parte de `php`

**funciones.php**

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

echo obtenerNombreProyecto($request);

function obtenerNombreProyecto($request){
  include 'conexion.php';
  $id_proyecto=$request['id'];

try{
 $sql= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = '$id_proyecto'");
    return json_encode($sql);
  } catch(Exception $e){
    $error = [];
    $error[] = "Tienes un error en la conexion";
    return json_encode( $error);
  }
}
```

Explicacion del los cambios en el fichero `funciones.php`

Al momento de enviar los datos en formato `Json` mediante `fetch` debes de tratarlos como un `string` enviado por el `body`  y no  como un `array` en la varible `$_POST`

Para eso es esta lineal de código  `$request =json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true)`

Luego debemos invocar el método `obtenerNombreProyecto($request)` pasando el valor que hemos recuperado.

Concejos que no has pedido:

- Recomendaría un nombre mas especifico para el fichero `funciones.php`
- En `javascript` Trata de utilizar funciones flecha para minimizar el codigo y que
  este sea mas limpio.

Comment: El console_log(json.stringify(datos) muestras un json vacío, pero ¿Por qué? Si la variable id_p está almacenado el ID del proyecto.                   Https://prnt.sc/Rz2zy-rgEnif

Comment: Si te devuelve  un json vacio es por que tienes un error en la conexion, He editado la respuesta

Comment: Sigue enviando vacío y sigue recibiendo vacío. (Programar es mi pasión) https://prnt.sc/Vqw0OcU0BP29